# Approaches of solving $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(x^2+x+1) \, dx $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(x^2+x+1) \, dx $$

What approach should I use to solve this integral particularly? Its answer is exact of $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos(\frac{3}{4})-\sin(\frac{3}{4}))$.

Comment: You may complete the square, apply the addition formula for cosine, and then utilize the [Fresnel integrals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Limits_as_x_approaches_infinity) to conclude.

Comment: From where did you get this integral and how do you know the exact answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on what @Sangchul Lee mentioned
$$x^2+x+1 = (x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}$$
Use the substitution, $$u = x+\frac{1}{2}$$
The integral will reduce to 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\cos(u^2+\frac{3}{4})\,du$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(\cos(u^2)\cos(\frac{3}{4})-\sin(u^2)\sin(\frac{3}{4}))\,du$$
Finally, we can use Euler's Formula $e^{ix} = \cos x+i\sin x$
$$e^{iu^2}=\cos(u^2)+i\sin(u^2)$$
We will only use either the real or the imaginary part for each integral.
Also, I hope you are aware of the fact that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$
With some appropriate adjustments, can you finish it off?